# Date.toLocaleDateString date formatting issue

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
const date = new Date(2020, 05, 10)
const options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
}
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en', options);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Why the output is June 10, 2020? I went through documentation but did not understand. Could somebody help me understand what's happening in above code.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I am not understanding the ouput.....was asked in a competitive exam.....

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#using_options   Month is config as `month: 'long'` so it will Show `June`, `short` will show `Jun`, but if you pass as `numeric` it will output month as 6, and Since month starts from 0-11, Since you passed  5 as month in Date constructor so June is the monthin output

Comment: @navnath Hey, nice explanation. How about post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}` month is config as `month: long` so it will show `June`, `short` will show `Jun`, but if you pass `numeric` for a month in `options` it will output interestingly month as `6`, and Since month starts from 0-11 and since you passed 5 as a month in Date constructor, so it will output June as a month.

[Ref for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#using_options)

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor.

There are multiple formats to pass date into the constructor. When using Individual date and time component values format, the second parameter is **monthIndex**. That is why 5 - corresponds to June, and for May you will have to use 4.

From the docs:

> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December. If a value greater than 11 is passed in, then those months will be added to the date; for example, new Date(1990, 12, 1) will return January 1st, 1991

As you can see this has nothing to do with your options. The month is **June** even before that.

```js
const date = new Date(2020, 05, 10)
console.log(date);
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en', options);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Note: You might be seeing a different **day**, depending but that is because the date returned initially is **platform-independent**. So it shows based on GMT.